# Child number inconsistency in ViewPager

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager whose `getCount();` changes based on a list of objects passed through the constructor. Using the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` I expect to see another page added. This seems to work correctly but when I remove an item from the mentioned list (used to calculate the `getCount()`) the ViewPager only removes the page successfully if its outside the offsetLimit.

**Exemple**: I have two pages and through a button I remove an item from the list. Then I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and expect to have only one page left, but... the second "Page" is still there even thought I cannot swipe to it!!!!

**How can I come around this?** I want to avoid re-instantiating the whole ViewPager with the fragments.

**CODE (simplification)**

```
public class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<String> list;

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<String> list) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

And this is inside the Activity:

```
        adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), items);

        final ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        findViewById(R.id.add).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                items.add("test");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.remove).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                items.remove(items.size() - 1);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

**With this I can add items from the `Activity` and update de adapter (it works) and remove ... its doesn't work. What can I do?**

Comment: it would be more helpful to paste a fuller code, what's happening when you click the button and how you're setting the data.

Comment: @Basil added the rest of the necessary code

Answer (score 0):

You can override `getItemPosition()` & return [POSITION_NONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter#position_none) in it.

---

**[getItemPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter#getitemposition) :**

Called when the host view is attempting to determine if an item's position has changed. Returns **POSITION_UNCHANGED** if the position of the given item has not changed or **POSITION_NONE** if the item is no longer present in the adapter.

The default implementation assumes that items will never change position and always returns **POSITION_UNCHANGED**.